# python: how to add a collections.defaultdict(int) to another?

Tags: python, collections

Something like statement [4] is what I'd like...

(obtained, clumsily & non-optimally, via statements [5] and [6])

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: d1 = defaultdict(int, dict(a=1, b=2, c=3))

In [3]: d2 = defaultdict(int, dict(a=10, c=30, d=40))

In [4]: d1 |= d2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'collections.defaultdict' and 'collections.defaultdict'

In [5]: def default_dict_add(d1, key, val): 
            d1[key] += val

In [6]: [default_dict_add(d1, k, d2[k]) for k in d2.keys()]
Out[6]: 
[None, None, None]

In [7]: d1
defaultdict(int, {'a': 11, 'b': 2, 'c': 33, 'd': 40})
```

Similar to what you can do with sets (statement # [44]

```
In [42]: s1 = {1, 2, 3}
s1 = {1, 2, 3}

In [43]: s2 = {10, 30, 40}
s2 = {10, 30, 40}

In [44]: s1 |= s2

In [45]: s1

Out[45]: 
{1, 2, 3, 10, 30, 40}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you're doing would be better suited for a `Counter`, which is in the same module as `defaultdict`.

```
d1 = Counter(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3))
d2 = Counter(dict(a=10, c=30, d=40))
d1 + d2
# Counter({'d': 40, 'c': 33, 'a': 11, 'b': 2})
```

Comment: You can also use `d1 += d2` if you want to modify `d1` as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c1 = Counter(d1)
>>> c2 = Counter(d2)
>>> c1 + c2
Counter({'d': 40, 'c': 33, 'a': 11, 'b': 2})
```

Or:

```
>>> {k: d1.get(k, 0) + d2.get(k, 0) for k in set(list(d1.keys()) + list(d2.keys()))}
{'a': 11, 'c': 33, 'b': 2, 'd': 40}
```